# Query on multiple values in Firebase, similar to IN() SQL functionality

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an array that looks like this:

```
validZipCodes = [
  "84606",
  "84605",
  "84601"
]
```

I'm querying some data like this:

```
var Jobs = firebase.child('Jobs');
```

I tried this:

```
var Jobs = firebase.child('Jobs').orderByChild('ZipCode').equalTo($scope.validZipCodes);
```

But it returned an error that it was an invalid data-type, is there anyway to say something like:

```
var Jobs = firebase.child('Jobs').orderByChild('ZipCode').inArray($scope.validZipCodes);
```

Or something like that.

Note that this is an array comparison & not querying text in an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I eventually did it:

With the foreach command you can easily manipulate data and then push it into an array to re-create a collection of data however you need it.

```
$scope.validZipCodes = [];
$scope.validContractorJobs = [];

var Jobs = firebase.child('Jobs');

contractorJobs.on('value', function(snap) {
            snap.forEach(function(job) {
                angular.forEach($scope.validZipCodes, function(value, key) {
                    if(job.val().ZipCode == value) {
                        $scope.validContractorJobs.push(job.val());
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase `.equalTo()` documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html) states that the `value` argument should be one of the following types: `String`, `Number`, `Null`, or `Boolean`.

- You are getting an `invalid data-type` error because you are not passing one of these types.
- There is no method like `.inArray()` (i.e. querying for equalTo multiple values).

You can review all of the Firebase Query Methods in the [Query documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/), which also  suggests:

> Read our documentation on [ordering](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data) and [querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) data for more information and examples.