# is there a way in angularfire to query for matching AND condition

Tags: firebase, angularfire

How we can query to firebase from angularfire to match two conditions.
i wanted to search below two conditions as **AND** match

1. if your key has **color red**
2. if your key has a **categories hex**

or what will be the validation in firebase like .indexOn or .validate

json is like

```
{

  "color" : {
    "-UqPNlZ8ddgdGMFSsD" : {
      "color" : "red",
      "categories" : {
        "hex" : {
          "subcategory" : [ "#111", "#333" ]
        }
      },
      "status" : "ok"
    },
    "-U9P4pBpYiId3ID64K" : {
      "color" : "blue",
      "categories" : {
        "hex" : {
          "subcategory" : [ "#ddd", "#eee" ]
        }
      },
      "status" : "ok"
    },
    "-U9UgOdffZdfdbSydF" : {
      "color" : "green",
      "categories" : {
        "hex" : {
          "subcategory" : [ "#333", "#555" ]
        }
      },
      "status" : "ok"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll answer below. But next time, show the code that you've tried already please. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query on multiple values in Firebase, similar to IN() SQL functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132451/query-on-multiple-values-in-firebase-similar-to-in-sql-functionality)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Firebase query can currently only contain one `orderBy...` call. They can also only query properties that are one level below the nodes being returned.

So you cannot implement your requirements in the way you probably initially hoped:

```
// THIS IS AN EXAMPLE THAT WILL NOT WORK
ref.child('color')
   .orderByChild('color').equalTo('red')
   .orderByChild('color/categories').equalTo('hex');
```

### Approach 1: add a new property that combines the properties you want to filter on

In some cases, you can get away with introducing a top-level property that combines the values you want to filter on. So let's say your color can only be in one category. You could then add an additional `colorcategory` property:

```
{

  "color" : {
    "-UqPNlZ8ddgdGMFSsD" : {
      "color" : "red",
      "colorcategory": "redhex",
      "categories" : {
        "hex" : {
          "subcategory" : [ "#111", "#333" ]
        }
      },
      "status" : "ok"
    },
    "-U9P4pBpYiId3ID64K" : {
      "color" : "blue",
      "colorcategory" : "bluehex",
      "categories" : {
        "hex" : {
          "subcategory" : [ "#ddd", "#eee" ]
        }
      },
      "status" : "ok"
    },
    "-U9UgOdffZdfdbSydF" : {
      "color" : "green",
      "colorcategory" : "greenhex",
      "categories" : {
        "hex" : {
          "subcategory" : [ "#333", "#555" ]
        }
      },
      "status" : "ok"
    }
}
```

And filter on that:

```
ref.child('color')
   .orderByChild('colorcategory').equalTo('redhex')
```

This will work when you have two single-value properties, even when they're on different levels in the JSON structure, since you're normalizing those properties and level into a single value on the right level.

But since your categories are multi-value, this approach also won't work. The only approach that I can think of is that you create a so-called secondary index on your data.

## Approach 2: create a secondary index on the properties that you want to filter on

An index in a NoSQL database is a data structure, much like a multi-column index in a relational database, that just exists for your queries. In this case, since you want to query on the combination of color and category, I'd expect an index `color_category` or maybe even `color_category_subcategory`.

```
color_category_subcategory:
  "red_hex_111": "-UqPNlZ8ddgdGMFSsD"
  "red_hex_333": "-UqPNlZ8ddgdGMFSsD"
  "blue_hex_ddd": "-U9P4pBpYiId3ID64K"
  "blue_hex_eee": "-U9P4pBpYiId3ID64K"
  "green_hex_333": "-U9UgOdffZdfdbSydF"
  "green_hex_555": "-U9UgOdffZdfdbSydF"
```

You will have to create and maintain this index from your own code , either in the client-side application or by running a server-side process that creates it. But once you have the index in place, you can query it:

```
ref.child('color_category_subcategory')
   .orderByKey().equalTo('red_hex_333')
   .on('value', function(snapshot) {...
```

Or by range:

```
ref.child('color_category_subcategory')
   .orderByKey().startAt('blue_hex').endAt('blue_hex~')
   .on('value', function(snapshot) {...
```

The `~` above is not a special operator, but just a character that happens to fall after all other characters in an ASCII sequence. So filtering `['blue_hex', 'blue_hex~']` will give all blue hexes.