# Firebase query of overlapping data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an Android app using Firebase. As I already understood, Firebase supports only queries for one property, so `order...` calls cannot be chained. The solution suggested in most of the cases is either a property combination in each item or creating a secondary index (for example, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151012/is-there-a-way-in-angularfire-to-query-for-matching-and-condition)).

However, this works mostly in case of `equalTo()` requests. My case is the following (and can be very common, I believe):

```
|- events
|    |
|    |- event1
|    |   |
|    |   |- name
|    |   |- startDate
|    |   |- endDate
|    |
|    |- event2
|    |   |
|    |   |- name
|    |   |- startDate
|    |   |- endDate
|    |
```

Now I want a date range overlapping query - give me all the events next month (event might span over several months).

Is this somehow possible with Firebase without client side processing or filtering? Any kind of tricks/combinations/indices that I can create in my DB?

I want to use the query results with FirebaseUI adapters, which don't support filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way for you

https://github.com/davideast/Querybase

Use this

```
 const databaseRef = firebase.database.ref().child('events');
 const querybaseRef = querybase.query(databaseRef);

 querybaseRef.where('startDate').lessThan(endDate);
 querybaseRef.where('endDate').greaterThan(startDate);
```

Comment: Then I have 2 sets of results which I have to manually intersect, right? The key part in my question was **"without client side processing or filtering"**